# how to get path to ruby.exe that is running current script on windows?

Tags: ruby, windows

There are variables in other scripts like:

python: `print(sys.executable)`

php: `echo PHP_BINARY."\n";`

is there anything like that in ruby ?

(ruby v.2.0)

Answer (score 1):

None of the answers below work reliably. They use static information but your ruby script might be executed by a ruby instance installed in a different than default path or in a path which is not in the PATH environment variable.

What you need to do is to use WIN32 api. In particular, [GetModuleHandle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683199%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [GetModuleFileName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/ms683197%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) functions need to be called. The first one gets a handle of actual process, the other one returns its path.

Example for inspiration:

```
require 'ffi'

module Helpers
  extend FFI::Library

  ffi_lib :kernel32

  typedef :uintptr_t, :hmodule
  typedef :ulong, :dword

  attach_function :GetModuleHandle, :GetModuleHandleA, [:string], :hmodule
  attach_function :GetModuleFileName, :GetModuleFileNameA, [:hmodule, :pointer, :dword], :dword

  def self.actualRubyExecutable
    processHandle = GetModuleHandle nil

    # There is a potential issue if the ruby executable path is
    # longer than 999 chars.
    rubyPath = FFI::MemoryPointer.new 1000
    rubyPathSize = GetModuleFileName processHandle, rubyPath, 999

    rubyPath.read_string rubyPathSize
  end
end

puts Helpers.actualRubyExecutable
```

On Linux, this information can be read from `/proc` directory.

Answer (score 0):

You may take a look at rubinius configure([build_ruby](https://github.com/srawlins/rubinius/blob/master/configure#L766-L776))

So, currently it looks as follows:

```
require 'rbconfig'

def build_ruby
  unless @build_ruby
    bin = RbConfig::CONFIG["RUBY_INSTALL_NAME"] || RbConfig::CONFIG["ruby_install_name"]
    bin += (RbConfig::CONFIG['EXEEXT'] || RbConfig::CONFIG['exeext'] || '')
    @build_ruby = File.join(RbConfig::CONFIG['bindir'], bin)
  end
  @build_ruby
end
```

I also tried the following:

```
require 'rbconfig'

File.join( RbConfig::CONFIG['bindir'],
           RbConfig::CONFIG['RUBY_INSTALL_NAME'] + RbConfig::CONFIG['EXEEXT']
         )
```

It works for me just as good.

Comment: This does not guarantee that you get the actual path of the executable. Just tried this on a custom ruby install, and it gives me the wrong path :(

Answer (score 0):

Try `%x(where ruby)` you must have the ruby.exe in your path for this to work so windows knows what 'ruby' your talking about.